# How to set property of a Siverlight control from .aspx.cs page?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

Here is my code

```
 public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }

    public string CurrentPage { get; set; }
```

Now I want to set the CurrentPage value from my .aspx page load event?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass in parameters into a Silverlight application from your calling web page you have to specify and assign the parameters inside the `<object ... />`
tag that you're using to embed the Silverlight app.
An example for such a parameter could be:

```
<object data="..." type="...">
  <param name="Parameter1" value="Value1" />
</object>
```

Inside the `Application_Startup` method (App.xaml.cs) you can query these parameters from the **StartupEventArgs' InitParams** collection.

If you just want to the get the hosting URL you can use this property from everywhere inside your Silverlight application:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri
```